# PayPal Integrations - DoReferenceTransaction and DoAuthorization

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

We have a requirement where we need to run the auto payment for the PayPal payment for next scheduled order's with out user interaction.

We are able to achieve this using Billing AgreementId that we processed during the user first transaction.

My question is We just need "DoReferenceTransactionReq" or after that even we need to do DoAuthorization. Please suggest.

Before this for the First transaction we are following api call:
1.SetExpressCheckoutReq
2.GetExpressCheckoutDetailsReq
3.DoExpressCheckOutPaymentReq

Answer (score 1):

If you've already gone through the Express Checkout flow and created a Sale or Authorization transaction there, then all you need to do is pass that transaction ID into DoReferenceTransaction to process the new amount.  DoAuthorization would simply create another fresh authorization and is not needed to run reference transactions.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation Andrew! I request you to look at my other PayPal issue

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066046/paypal-doexpresscheckoutpayment-validation-issue

Comment: Hi Andrew, Our scenario is OFFLINE scneario, where there will no user interaction, but based on Billing aggrement id created during the inital transcation, we call doReferenceTransaction an doAuth. Do you mean to say, if we have a doAuth call there is no significance of it. The transaction is still complete with just doRefernceTransaction. if so can we remove the doAuth call.